# Can we encode a torsor as a binary function on the isomorphism classes of objects?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, algebraic-number-theory, topos-theory, torsors

Let $G$ be a group object in a topos $\mathcal{T}$. Then we have the notion of a $G$-torsor in $\mathcal{T}$, and the set of isomorphism classes of such objects is denoted $H^1(\mathcal{T};G)$. For example, $\mathcal{T}$ is often the étale topos of some scheme $X$, and $G$ is a group scheme over $X$, and this defines $H^1_\text{ét}(X;G)$.

Given such a torsor $V$, we can consider its functor of points $U \mapsto V(U)$ for $U \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{T})$. Then $V(U)$ is always a pseudo-torsor under $G(U)$, meaning that it is either a set with simply-transitive $G(U)$ action OR the empty set with the unique action. In fact, it has exactly two possibilities for its isomorphism class as an abstract $G(U)$-set.

This defines a function $H^1(\mathcal{T};G) \to \operatorname{Hom}_\text{set}(\pi_0(\mathcal{T}),\mathbb{F}_2)$ sending $V$ to the function $f_V$ such that $f_V(U) = 1$ iff $V(U)$ is empty.

My main question: assuming $G$ is fixed, what kind of equivalence relation does this define on $H^1(\mathcal{T};G)$? For example, it would seem to be invariant under all of the automorphisms of $G$.

As a toy example, consider $\mu_n$ in the etale site of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then any $a \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ gives rise to a torsor corresponding to the $n$th roots of $a$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. The binary function seems to send a finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ to $0$ iff $K$ contains an $n$th root of $a$. The automorphism group of $\mu_n$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. It would seem that a preimage under this map is indeed a $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$-orbit, since $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[n]{a}] \cong \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[n]{b}]$ iff $a \cong b^k \pmod{(\mathbb{Q}^\times)^n}$ for some $k$ relatively prime to $n$.

I'm also wondering: what is the nature of the image? The target has the structure of an infinite affine space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, so does the image have any kind of algebraic structure?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but I will show:

1. The map is indeed $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$-equivariant (for the trivial action on the target).
2. The map naturally factors through $\pi_0(\mathcal T)$ (again equivariantly).
3. The naïve guess that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ acts transitively on the fibres is not correct (even for the factored map in (2)).

(If I understand your notation correctly, $\pi_0(\mathcal T)$ means objects up to isomorphism, and not the pro-representable left adjoint $\pi_0$ to $\nu^* \colon \mathbf{Set} \to \mathcal T$, where $\nu \colon \mathcal T \to \mathbf{Set}$ is the terminal morphism.)

For (1) and (2), note that an isomorphism $\phi \colon G \to H$ induces a map $H^1(\mathcal T,G) \to H^1(\mathcal T,H)$ that can be constructed on torsors as follows: given a $G$-torsor $m \colon G \times V \to V$, let $H$ act on $V$ via
$$H \times V \xrightarrow{(\phi^{-1},1)} G \times V \xrightarrow m V.$$
To see that this indeed induces the pushforward $H^1(\mathcal T,G) \to H^1(\mathcal T,H)$, one can use for instance use cocycles.

This shows that the map $H^1(\mathcal T,G)/{\operatorname{Aut}(G)} \to \pi_0(\mathcal T)$ taking $G \times V \to V$ to $V$ is well-defined. Note that $f_V$ only depends on the underlying object $V$, so we get a factorisation
\begin{align*}
H^1(\mathcal T,G) \twoheadrightarrow H^1(\mathcal T,G)\big/{\operatorname{Aut}(G)} \xrightarrow f \pi_0(\mathcal T) &\xrightarrow g {\operatorname{Map}}\bigl(\pi_0(\mathcal T),\mathbf F_2\bigr).
\end{align*}
There are now two questions: whether $f$ is injective, and whether $g$ is injective on the image of $f$.

One easily sees that $g$ is not injective in general; for instance $V$ and $V \amalg V$ have points over the same $U \in \mathcal T$, since $V$ and $V \amalg V$ mutually admit maps to each other. In the locally finite case that you're interested in, this type of example does not occur for degree reasons, but you could look at things like $V \amalg V \amalg W$ and $V \amalg W \amalg W$. (I do not have an example where there are $G$-torsor structures on these, but I see no reason why this couldn't exist.)

But in fact, $f$ is not injective, even in the case you mention of $G = \boldsymbol \mu_n$. An element $a \in \mathbf Q^\times$ gives a class $[a] \in \mathbf Q^\times/(\mathbf Q^\times)^n \cong H^1(\mathbf Q,\boldsymbol \mu_n)$, which as $\boldsymbol\mu_n$-torsor is given by the scheme $V_a = V(x^n-a) \subseteq \mathbf A^1_{\mathbf Q}$ with the obvious $\boldsymbol\mu_n$-action.

**Example.** Let $n = 8$ and consider the elements $a = -1$ and $b = -16$ in $\mathbf Q$. Then we claim that $V_a \cong V_b$ as schemes but $[a] \neq [b]$ in $H^1(\mathbf Q,\boldsymbol\mu_8)/{\operatorname{Aut}(\boldsymbol\mu_8)}$.

For the first statement, note that $x^8+1$ is the minimal polynomial of a primitive $16^{\text{th}}$ root of unity $\zeta_{16}$, so $V_a \cong \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Q(\zeta_{16})$. In $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{16})$, the element $\beta = (1+i)\zeta_{16}$ satisfies $\beta^8 = -16$, showing that $x^8+16$ has a root in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{16})$. Since $\beta^4 = -4i$, we conversely see that $i$ and therefore $\zeta_{16} = \tfrac{\beta}{(1+i)}$ is in $\mathbf Q(\beta)$, so $\mathbf Q(\zeta_8) = \mathbf Q(\beta)$ and $V_a \cong V_b$.

For the final statement, since $\operatorname{Aut}(\boldsymbol\mu_8) \cong (\mathbf Z/8)^\times$, we have to show that $(-16)^j \notin (-1)(\mathbf Q^\times)^8$ for any odd $j$. This follows since $v_2\bigl((-16)^j\bigr) = 4j \equiv 4 \pmod 8$ whereas $v_2(-1) = 0$. $\square$

I learned this example from Robin Zhang's honours thesis [The Grunwald–Wang theorem and isomorphic radical extensions](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Erzhang/files/HonorsThesis.pdf), Example 3.4.4 (which in turn attributes — without mentioning a title — a note of Brian Conrad). But presumably this is somehow 'classical'.